# Unable to add values dynamically in dropdown list using struts2 and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

What I am doing is ,first of all in action class I am fetching details and adding it into one arraylist object i.e arrayist and I want to display that values in dropdown list in jsp page but i haven't succeded. Action class is working perfectly .When the user logins I have fired that query in that action class only .
Below is my jsp page code:

```
<div>
    <select name="eventName" 
            class="billlistbox1" 
            list="dataForBillsJspList" 
            listValue="eventName"/>
</div>
```

Here `dataForBillsJspList` is the arraylist object in which all data is added when the user logins in to the application which is working perfectly. I referred many stackoverflow's post as well but in vain :(
Any help would be appreciated . Thanks :)

Comment: is it a typo using struts2 tag?

Comment: what does typo means ?

Comment: It would be too long answer.

Comment: Lol okay sir...but i got it working using some another way ..should i post it as a answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In your action class;you should have arrayList attribute'dataForBillsJspList' and you should have getter method for this attribute.Then you can bind this arrayList of action class in jsp like that:.

Comment: but she has already told that the action class is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved by referring to this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-dynamicstruts/). I hope it may help others too :)